# Why doesn't the preprocessor's token pasting operator ## work on variables?

Tags: c, variables, c-preprocessor

```
#if !defined(STDIO_H) && !defined(STDLIB_H)
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
#endif
#if !defined(LIMITS_H)
    #include<limits.h>
#endif
#if !defined(MATH_H)
    #define pow(a,b)    {\
                            int i=1,p=1;\
                            while(i<=b)\
                            {\
                                p=p*a;\
                                i++;\
                            }\
                            printf("%d\n",p);\
                        }
    #define join(a,b)   a##b
#endif
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter a b : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    pow(a,b);
    printf("%d\n",join(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

The error is in line `printf("%d",join(a,b));` but it works perfectly if i replace a & b with constants like 56 and 34.Error is ab undeclared first use in function.

Comment: `!defined(STDIO_H)` - all this is strange. `stdio.h` shouldn't declare `STDIO_H`.. Well `join(a,b)` joins `a` with `b`, resulting in the `ab`. What did you expect? What is your question?

Comment: sorry actually playing with preprocessors to become an all round great coder in c

Comment: Your first goal as an All-Round Great Coder in C [tm] should be to use the preprocessor sparingly.

Comment: yup understood thanks

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor runs at compile time. So the '##' operator is evaluated at compile time. You cannot use it with values that are determined at runtime.

What happens here is that `a##b` is simply translated to `ab`, hence the error `ab undefined`.

Comment: thanks understood the `pow(a,b);` macro works for run time input so expected the same for `join(a,b);`.

Comment: No. `pow(a,b)` literally substitutes it for the `{ int i=1,.... }`. It works with text too.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is not relevant when “preprocessing” is done. A conforming C implementation could do preprocessor substitution at any time up to and including program execution (a C implementation written as an on-demand interpreter can conform to the C standard). What is relevant is the semantic level at which macro replacement is done: It is done with *preprocessing tokens* using rules specified by the C standard that do not provide for substituting the values of objects.